# boto set_contents_from_file from existing boto.s3.key.Key

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I'm trying to do something that might not be possible, but is not apparently so in the documentation. Essentially, I want to set the contents of an s3.key.Key using a different s3.key.Key using the set_contents_from_file method. It reports the following error:

```
 'Key' object has no attribute 'tell'
```

Here is some code that reproduces the issue.

```
import boto
from boto.s3.key import Key
s3 = boto.connect_s3()
b = s3.get_bucket("XXXXXX")
ef = b.get_key("figures/test-figure.png") ## this file exists in b.


In [4]: ef.exists()
Out[4]: True


nk = Key(b, "my-new-key.png")
nk.set_contents_from_file(ef)


in set_contents_from_file(self, fp, headers, replace, cb, num_cb, policy, md5, reduced_redundancy, query_args, encrypt_key, size, rewind)
   1222             # programs remain that assume the older auto-rewind interface.
   1223             if not isinstance(fp, KeyFile):
-> 1224                 spos = fp.tell()
   1225                 fp.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
   1226                 if fp.tell() == spos:

AttributeError: 'Key' object has no attribute 'tell'
```

I've tried to call: 'ef.open_read()' first, but nothing really seems to affect the behavior. I am using:

```
boto==2.38.0
botocore==1.2.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The S3 service supports a server-side COPY operation that seems like it would be perfect for your use case.  Something like this should work:

```
import boto
s3 = boto.connect_s3()
bucket = s3.get_bucket('my_bucket')
key = bucket.get_key('my_key_to_copy')
key.copy('my_bucket', 'my_new_key')
```

This will create a new object in the bucket which is a copy of the original object and it all happens on the server-side.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I should probably figure out how to make that work, its only that I'm interacting with an api that only accepts a file-like thing, so I wanted to get such an object from the key - I've just worked around it by writing to a tempfile, setting seek to 0, and passing along that file handle. Maybe I'm missing an obviously better solution.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to copy the file from S3 to your local machine and then back to S3 but perhaps there is something I don't understand.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm asking the wrong way. I wanted an API that accepts these schemes: s3://, file://, http:// and yields a file handle for another API that may or may not store things in S3. The API was built around file-like because it's common. Certainly it can be worked around, but it's clearly more work.

Comment: I'm going to file a bug against boto - do you think that is incorrect? I've seen you (@garnaat) answer a lot of these questions so I figure you are in the know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:-

```
access_key, secret_key = your_access_key, yoursecret_key
conn = boto.connect_s3(access_key, secret_key)
bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucketname)
k = Key(bucket)
k.key = 'somekey'
k.set_contents_from_filename(file_path
```